# gas fireplace will not shut off with wall switch

Tags: fireplace

Fireplace has a remote switch.  The switch is good.  The fireplace stays on with switch in off position.The switch can be unplugged and still fireplace will stay on. Is the gas valve just stuck open?

Comment: Your garage door doesn't close if you take the battery out of the remote either. :) Does the fireplace have a local switch?

Comment: is it a wired or wireless remote?

Comment: Battery in remote and battery in the receiving unit under f/pgood?